# How do I check if a certain item has been taken out of a chest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I am trying to make a custom crafting data pack for Minecraft. I have found some tutorials that show me how, but all of them use droppers that craft the item instantly after putting the items in. Currently I have a chest that crafts the items but I want to be able to detect once a player has taken out the crafted item so I can delete the items used in the recipe.

Comment: What item are you crafting? Does it have tags, custom name. What slot?

Comment: the recipe i am using to test is a diamond in slot 1b and a nether star in slot 10b. it gives me a netherite block in 15b i just want to know how to detect once the player has taken the netherite block so i can get rid of the items used for the recipe. it doesn't have any tags or custom name.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
execute unless data block 785 61 526 {Items:[{Slot:15b,id:"minecraft:netherite_block"}]} run say taken
```

If you want to empty the chest use:

```
data merge block 785 61 526 {Items:[]}
```

Comment: this works and is awesome but how would this work if I had multiple recipes? if I run this under tick it will reset the chest all the time which would give the player no time to even craft the item.

Comment: so u want to delete only certan items?

Comment: no. but if i run this command every tick it will delete all the items once you put them in the chest because there isn't a netherite block in slot 15 yet. this would give the player no time to put in the items to craft the netherite block.